# Trying to set a scoped variable that will change with a jquery change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, color-picker

I am not sure if I am doing this right. I am trying to set the background of a div by choosing a color with a color picker. I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/835/) to show what i am trying to do. However the TargetColor doesn't seem to be binding. Am I going about this the wrong way? Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this with an example? The ending idea would be to change the colors of all the containers on the page on color change (the number of containers could be pretty high and new one can be made which is why the style tag is being used).

Comment: Why the -1?  Question seems reasonable

Comment: I think it was the guy that initially commented. I didn't -1 his but he must've thought I did and did it to mine.

Comment: I suggest a few changes to the fiddle and resubmitting this question: 1) Call $scope.IntializeColor somewhere 2) Move all the DOM manip out of a controller and into a directive, and 3) don't use ng-Style, instead have the directive manipulate your css to change the color of a css class, and have that css class assigned to every container whos color would change.

Comment: @RoyTruelove I honestly do not know how to do number 2. I have watched and read so many things on how directives are suppose to work and I still cant figure out how to make my own. I can do it with something basic but when it comes to something like I am trying to do I can't even get close and cannot find a good example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle with a directive to handle that: http://jsfiddle.net/g/LAJCa/

As mentionned in the comments, you should'nt do DOM manipulations outside directives, you'll not benefit a lot from angular if you don't respect the guidelines: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller

Comment: I posted this question on reddit and someone also posted [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/864/). Is there a way you are using a directive that is "more correct" then the other? Or is it simply two different ways to do it. Also thank you very much for that. I seem to be having a difficult time understanding how directive with angular are suppose to work.

Comment: It's just 2 different ways but with mine you don't have to worry about stectrum messing with the parent element and you can pass options to the stectrum init with an options attribute, so i would say mine is more complete ;)

Comment: and the reddit one do not propagate changes from outside the color picker to the picker